# Log shipping report to show average daily volume?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, log-shipping

Is there a SQL log shipping report (or query) that I can run to see what my average daily log shipping volume is in terms of gigabytes of log data shipped (by DB or in total)?

Answer (score 1):

Went with this to see total log backup volume for a week by DB

```sql
SELECT a.database_name, ( (SUM(a.compressed_backup_size)) / 1048576.0) AS CompressedMBSize  
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset a 
WHERE a.type = 'L'
AND a.backup_finish_date BETWEEN '02-13-2022 00:00:00' AND '02-19-2022 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.database_name
ORDER BY CompressedMBSize DESC
```